# INSERT INTO SELECT with a LEFT JOIN to prevent duplicates, only prevents duplicates already in the table

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, left-join

Regarding this method of preventing the insertion of duplicates:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT t2.col1, 
       t2.col2 
FROM   table2 t2 
       LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
         ON t2.col1 = t1.col1 
            AND t2.col2 = t1.col2 
WHERE  t1.col1 IS NULL
```

From my testing I can see that this will prevent any duplicate col1/col2 combinations coming in from Table_2 that are already in Table_1, but that it will not prevent the same col1/col2 combination being passed in from Table_2 more than once. Am I right in thinking that the reference to Table_1 in the LEFT JOIN can be thought of as a 'snapshot' of Table_1 at the point before the query starts and that it therefore does not have any visibility of new col1/col2 combinations that have been added from Table_2 as part of the query itself?

If this is correct and is there a way to check for dupes within the incoming source table as well without resorting to an extra step for source deduplication (in my real world case the source will be two tables INNER JOINed)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct on the "snapshot" point: any insertions into `table1` in this query will not affect the `LEFT JOIN table1`.

But you would still need a `DISTINCT` to guarantee uniqueness from the queried data.

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT DISTINCT
       t2.col1, 
       t2.col2 
FROM   table2 t2 
       LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
         ON t2.col1 = t1.col1 
            AND t2.col2 = t1.col2 
WHERE  t1.col1 IS NULL
```

---

However:

- `LEFT JOIN` is a poor man's replacement for `NOT EXISTS` and `EXCEPT` which the optimizer understands much better
- You should always specify column names in an `INSERT`

So your code should look like one of these options:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
SELECT DISTINCT
       t2.col1, 
       t2.col2 
FROM   table2 t2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM table1 t1 
         WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1 
            AND t2.col2 = t1.col2);



INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
SELECT DISTINCT
       t2.col1, 
       t2.col2 
FROM   table2 t2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                    -- or you can use EXISTS/EXCEPT
       SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2
       INTERSECT
       SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
       FROM table1 t1);



INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
SELECT                  -- EXCEPT implies DISTINCT
       t2.col1, 
       t2.col2 
FROM   table2 t2
EXCEPT
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1;
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. This is very helpful.